# D3: use .map() to rearrange an array of data

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

If I have data like this...

```
var dataset = [
    { apples: 5, oranges: 10, grapes: 22 },
    { apples: 4, oranges: 12, grapes: 28 },
    { apples: 2, oranges: 19, grapes: 32 },
    { apples: 7, oranges: 23, grapes: 35 },
    { apples: 23, oranges: 17, grapes: 43 }
];
```

How could I use the .map() method  to rearrange the data so that it is an array of arrays, each array represents a category (apples, oranges, grapes) and each object in that array is the data.  The x is an ID marker.

```
var dataset = [
    [
            { x: 0, y: 5 },
            { x: 1, y: 4 },
            { x: 2, y: 2 },
            { x: 3, y: 7 },
            { x: 4, y: 23 }
    ],
    [
            { x: 0, y: 10 },
            { x: 1, y: 12 },
            { x: 2, y: 19 },
            { x: 3, y: 23 },
            { x: 4, y: 17 }
    ],
    [
            { x: 0, y: 22 },
            { x: 1, y: 28 },
            { x: 2, y: 32 },
            { x: 3, y: 35 },
            { x: 4, y: 43 }
    ]
```

];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is for each key (fruit), use a `map` to create all the objects for that fruit:

```
newDataset = ["apples", "oranges", "grapes"].map(function(n){
    return dataset.map(function(d, i){
               return { x: i, y: d[n] };
           });
    });
```

Note that `i` in the anonymous function passed to `map` is the index of the `dataset` array, so can be used as the ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in one pass with `.reduce()`

```
dataset.reduce(function(previous, current, index, array){
    return Object.keys(current).map(function(d, i){
        return previous[i].concat([{'x' : i, 'y' : current[d]}]);
    });
}, [[],[],[]]);
```

This starts with an empty skeleton of arrays, and populates one internal object in each of the arrays with each iteration.

Of course, this involves looping over the keys inside each object while building the new array, so the loop itself is no more efficient than the one in mdml's answer, but it doesn't have the initial assignment, and hence is one operation more efficient, and therefore obviously the superior answer :P